How to Inject Color and Control Size of Dynamically Fetched SVGs in React?
I'm working on a React application where I need to fetch SVG icons from a URL and apply a custom color to them based on a value from my Redux store. Additionally, I want to ensure that the SVG scales correctly within its container without overflowing or distorting.
Here's what I've tried so far:
const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
const colorFromStore = useSelector(getUserColor);

const fetchSvgIcon = async (url: string) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://corsproxy.io/?${url}`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8',
            },
            responseType: 'text',
        });
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response.data, 'text/xml');
        const svg = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
        if (svg && svgRef.current) {
            svgRef.current.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching SVG:", error);
    }
};

<svg ref={svgRef} color={colorFromStore} />


However, I'm facing a couple of issues:
Variable SVG Sizes: Each SVG I fetch has a different size, and I'm struggling to keep them within the boundaries of their container. I tried manipulating the size using CSS, inline styles, and even adjusting the viewBox, but I'm still facing issues. When I use small values for viewBox, the SVG becomes larger, and vice versa. It seems like each SVG requires a different viewBox to fit correctly.
Applying Custom Color: While I'm trying to apply the color using the color property, I'm not sure if this is the best approach for modifying the SVG's fill or stroke color dynamically.
Can someone guide me on how I can:
Correctly inject my custom color into the fetched SVG?
Ensure the SVG scales properly within its container without distorting or overflowing?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Or instead of fetching each SVG separatly, create a native JavaScript Web Component <svg-icon> React 19 now fully supports them

what if im not using react 19,
is there a way to do it somehow close to what i have so far?

Sure, you just have to do more work in React to wrap Custom Elements/Web Components: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components#custom-html-elements
